# iOS duckOthers over ringtone

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

Does anyone know if there is a way to play an audio MP3 over ringtone?

Using this:

```
try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers);
```

audio starts after phone stop ringing.